# Access windows clipboard history from past sessions

Tags: windows, windows-10, clipboard

A week ago I had a quite important link in my clipboard that I lost. I want to find it again. I have Windows 10 feature `Clipboard History` enabled. So with `Win + V` I can access my clipboard for this session (as far as I understand). How can I access the clipboard from previous sessions? Are they being logged somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access your clipboard history in Windows 10 with <kbd>[image]</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

This only contains the last 25 items, and if you use the clipboard as much as I do that is unlikely to still be there.

For a future solution I suggest going with harrymc's post and installing a clipboard alternative, in order to get your important url back I would try your **browser history** instead. For most browsers this can be accessed by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

I think that your data is lost.

There might be a small chance if you
ever turned on "Sync across devices" in
*Settings > System > Clipboard*.

You need a third-party product for avoiding such problems,
as the Windows clipboard is pretty lame by itself.

An example is
[ClipAngel](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clip-angel/files/)
and its
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/clip-angel-is-an-extension-to-the-standard-windows-clipboard-created-by-tormozit/).

Comment: My favorite windows clipboard history widget is Ditto - lots of configuration options, saves me lots of keystrokes daily. https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/